# Preventing nested DIVs to wrap (without specifying parent width)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

In the code below I have 2 divs, each having two nested divs. When the browser window is re-sized under Firefox/IE8 it all works well - The rightmost parent div falls down under the first one.

Under IE6, however (or IE8 with compatibility mode) the child divs in the second div wrap. To make things worse, it happens DESPITE the fact I've set a max-height to the div.

How do I make IE6 behave like IE8/Firefox in this case? How can I tell the DIVs not to wrap? Note that the text is dynamic so I can't set width to the parent.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.parent
{
float: left;
border: solid 1px black;
height: 30px;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.child
{
float: left;
border: solid 1px grey;
width: auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
What is up, guy What is up, guy
</div>
<div class="child">
What is up, guy What is up, guy
</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
What is up, guy What is up, guy
</div>
<div class="child">
What is up, guy What is up, guy
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE6 does not support max-height, for one thing

Comment: I'd be happy even if just 'height' worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was answered to me at [DocType](http://doctype.com/preventing-nested-divs-wrap-without-specifying-parent-width):

```
.child {
    display:inline;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    width: auto;}
```

Works fine in IE6 and FF3.5

This happens because the divs are no longer block level elements floated, but they are now inline elements. depending on your objective, this may or may not be a good answer.

I think that the root of the problem lies in IE6's "undersanding" of "white-space: nowrap". In IE6's case it works only with inline elements.

Comment: Can you add more details to your answer? As is, it's just a link, and it's not immediately obvious how the link answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional comments to get IE to use `height`, and use `max-height` everywhere else.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/stylesheet" />

<!--[if IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
.parent {
  height: 30px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Even if I just put 'height' in it (without condition), it still ignores the height.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you specify the width in percentage? That should make it expand and shrink like you want without wrapping.

Comment: I'm unable to specify percentage since in my layout there is unknown number of parent boxes and I don't know neither they relative nor fixed width. It would solve the issue however.